# MapKit annotation how to add detail disclosure info button?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkitannotation

I am putting `annotation` on a map and after clicking the pin,  there should be a `detail disclosure info button`on the right side, so I can add more code after tapping the button. But when I run the project, clicking on the pin, there is no `info button`shows up. Can anyone provide code to add `disclosure info button`?

I am expecting an info button on the right: [image]

My Code:

```
extension ViewController: MKMapView{


func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {



  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `MKAnnotationView` and add a button to it. So:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }

        if let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "") {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation
            return annotationView
        } else {
            let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation:annotation, reuseIdentifier:"")
            annotationView.isEnabled = true
            annotationView.canShowCallout = true

            let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
            return annotationView
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Rob, do you mean something like this `if annotation.isMember(of:MKUserLocation.self){ return nil }`?

Comment: @Rob, updated the example. Thanks again for the feedback!